# Database in celery task is out dated

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have Django==2.2.8 and celery==4.3.0, redis as broker.

Have very simple `drf` view to create `BankEntry`.

```py
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        instance = serializer.save()
        bank_entry = BankEntries.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
        async_task = async_create_transactions.delay(bank_entry.pk) <--- celery task
```

```py
@celery_app.task()
def async_create_transactions(entry_id):
    bank_entry = BankEntries.objects.filter(pk=entry_id).first()
    if bank_entry: <---- HERE SOMETIMES BANK_ENTRY IS NONE, But why, we just created it
        return bank_entry.create_entries()
```

Have no idea why, but in `async_create_transactions` I can get just created BankEntry.
I'm sure that celery setup use same database, because in a next `async_create_transactions` call, I can see previous BankEntry but not the current one.

I don't have, hooks, signals, postgresql functions and other side effects.

Comment: Are you using uuid as primary key in `BankEntries` table?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar Updated the code, to show that I'm sure that bank_entry is created and replaced pk with id

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is that your background task is trying to access the database entry before the `serializer.save()` has been completed fully. I have run into a similar problem before.

What you can do is add a short delay after you invoke your `async_create_transactions` which will give time for the record saving to be complete. So you could do something like this:

```
from time import sleep

@celery_app.task()
def async_create_transactions(entry_id):
    sleep(1)
    bank_entry = BankEntries.objects.filter(pk=entry_id).first()
    if bank_entry: 
        return bank_entry.create_entries()
```

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it has worked for me in many cases.

Comment: in my case async_create_transactions always get entry_id that means that object was created. Doc says that pk is calculated by database https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys

Comment: yes, time.sleep(3) works for me, just curious how even that can happens, model.create() is sync function if I got id of object, that's mean insert query is already done

Comment: Take a look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222977/django-with-celery-existing-object-not-found